# Slow Query Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, database, catalog, slow-response

One of the query is taking `1,197.66ms` as per the DB profiler.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='53' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON product.entity_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_1` AS `stock_status_index` ON product.sku = stock_status_index.sku INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5e2b103532d2e6_49335793` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE (stock_status_index.is_salable = 1)
```

and one of the queries is taking `1,343.69ms` as per the DB profiler.

```
 SELECT `main_table`.`value`, count(main_table.value) AS `count` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5e2b102f151459_58989318` AS `entities` ON main_table.entity_id = entities.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON main_table.source_id = product.entity_id INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_1` AS `stock_index` ON product.sku = stock_index.sku WHERE (main_table.attribute_id = '83') AND (main_table.store_id = '1' ) AND (stock_index.is_salable = 1)) AS `main_table` GROUP BY `value`
```

and one of the queries is taking `1,165.11ms` as per the DB profiler.

```
 SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `stock_status_index`.`is_salable`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='53' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON product.entity_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_1` AS `stock_status_index` ON product.sku = stock_status_index.sku INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5e2b103532d2e6_49335793` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE (stock_status_index.is_salable = 1) ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` asc, `e`.`entity_id` DESC LIMIT 9
```

and one of the queries is taking `1,164.40ms` as per the DB profiler.

```
SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_1` AS `stock` ON stock.sku = entity.sku WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 116890) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '144') AND (stock.is_salable = 1) ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
```

I migrated the DB on rds still there is no speed improvement in the site.

How to improve these slow Magento Queries.

Comment: There are no question that can be answered

Comment: This is not an question.